# Can I use 2 MaterialApp Widgets in one application?

Tags: flutter, dart, architecture

I want to use 2 material app widgets for application because a material of MaterialApp Widgets I use for customer and another I use it for executor. Where I will be store routes of customer in first MaterialApp Widget and I will be store routes of executor in another MaterialApp.

But, I don't know, I think It is bad approach.

How you think, which approach is the better way?
And if my approach is bad then why is bad and which problems will be?
And If I add 2 MaterialApp Widgets my application will be more much heavy than I use one widget?